# docker multi container: Linking wordpress container with mysql container within a docker network

Tags: docker, wordpress, containers

I tried a simple tutorial to up and run WordPress in multi-container by following simple commands.

```
docker pull mysql
docker pull wordpress

docker run --name yourSql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123 -d mysql:latest
docker run --name letterPress --link yourSql:mysql -p 8888:80 -d wordpress
```

everything runs perfectly fine, and if I access wordpress container with its ip address and port like 
http://172.18.0.2:8888

This starts a wizard of WordPress where this wizard **does not ask** any credentials related to MySQL (hostname, database name, username and password)

However, if I try to run these both `containers` in a docker `network` then it ask me all the credentials **(now it's not automatic)**

```
docker network create blog-network

docker run --name yourSql --net blog-network -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123 -d mysql:latest
docker run --name letterPress --net blog-network --link yourSql:mysql -p 8888:80 -d wordpress
```

Now if I access the WordPress container with url, the wizard starts but this time it asks me about all the credentials related to MySQL.

so my question is **why now it's asking about the credentials?**